# Number of solutions to $x^{3^{n+1}+1} = 1$ in a field of order $3^{2n+1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field such that $|F|=3^{2n+1}$ and $r=3^{n+1}$. I want to find the number of $x\in F$ that satisfies the equation $x^{r+1}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Say we want to count the solutions to $x^k=e$ in a cyclic group of order $m$. We may as well write everything additively and work in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Writing $\overline{k}=k/\gcd(m,k)$ and $\overline{m}=m/\gcd(m,k)$,

$$kx\equiv 0~\bmod m ~\iff~ \overline{k}x\equiv 0\bmod\overline{m} ~\iff~ x\equiv 0\bmod \overline{m}$$

The first $\Leftrightarrow$ follows from dividing/multiplying by $\gcd(m,k)$, and the second by multiplying by the inverse of $\overline{k}$ mod $\overline{m}$ (which exists since $\gcd(\overline{m},\overline{k})=1$). Therefore, the solutions $x$ mod $m$ are precisely $\ell\overline{m}$ for $0\le \ell<\gcd(m,k)$, of which there are $\gcd(m,k)$ many.

If $F$ is a field of order $3^{2n+1}$, then $|F^\times|=3^{2n+1}-1$ and with the Euclidean algorithm we may calculate the number of solutions to $x^{3^{n+1}+1}=1$ as

$$\begin{array}{ll} \gcd(3^{2n+1}-1,3^{n+1}+1) & =\gcd\big(3^{2n+1}-1-3^n(3^{n+1}+1)),3^{n+1}+1\big) \\ & = \gcd(-3^n-1,3^{n+1}+1) \\ & =\gcd(3^n+1,3^{n+1}+1) \\ & = \gcd\big(3^n+1,3^{n+1}+1-3(3^n+1)\big) \\ & = \gcd(3^n+1,-2) \\ & =2. \end{array}$$

Answer (score -1):

Well, since the multiplicative field of $\;\Bbb F\;$ , namely $\;\Bbb F^*:=\Bbb F-\{0\}\;$ is cyclic of order $\;3^{2n+1}-1\;$, we get that forall

$$x\in\Bbb F^*\;,\;\;x^{3^{2n+1}-1}=1\;$$

You though want some $\;x\in\Bbb F^*\;$ s.t.

$$x^{3^{n+1}+1}=1\iff \left(3^{n+1}+1\right)\mid\left(3^{2n+1}-1\right)$$

Try to take it from here.

Comment: Ok! Actually I want to know is it possible that $\left(3^{n+1}+1\right)\mid\left(3^{2n+1}-1\right$?

Comment: I may be missing something, but the $\iff$ just isn't true? $x^{r+1} = 1$ may hold even if $r+1$ doesn't divide $|\mathbb{F}^\times|$. Conversely just because $r+1$ divides $|\mathbb{F}^\times|$ doesn't mean $x^{r+1} = 1$. So neither direction of the $\iff$ holds.

Comment: @6005 In a group of order $\;n\;$ , if some element $\;x\;$ is of order $\;m\;$  then Lagrange's theorem gives us $\;m\,\mid\,n\;$ , and you have the implication "$\;\implies$" since $\;x^{3^{n+1}+1}=1\implies \text{ord}\,x\mid\,(3^{n+1}+1)\;$ . On the other hand, if we have $\;m\,\mid\,n\;$ then there exists an element of order $\;m\;$, since $\;F^*\;$ is *cyclic* and it thus has a unique subgroup (also cyclic) of any order dividing $\;|F^*|\;$ . Anyway, if you think some implication isn't true please do show a counterexample. I amy have missed something and this is three years old...

Comment: @DonAntonio Take $x = 1$, $n = 0$. Then $x^{3^{n+1} + 1} = 1$ but $4$ doesn't divide $2$.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning on the $\Leftarrow$ direction, although the quantification on $x$ is confusingly implied. Nevertheless the $\Rightarrow$ direction is wrong because the LHS is that $x^{r+1} = 1$, i.e. order of $x$ divides $r+1$, not that the order of $x$ is $r+1$.